# Explain: If $\left \{ a_n \right \}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges with a limit $a$, then any subsequence converges with the same limit.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation

**Lemma**. If $\left \{ a_n \right \}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges with a limit $a$, then any subsequence converges with the same limit.

**Proof**. Let   $\left \{ a_{n_k} \right \}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a subsequence of $\left \{ a_n \right \}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. That $\left \{ a_n \right \}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $a$ means, that for all $\epsilon>0$, dere exists a $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ yields
$$|a_n - a|<\epsilon$$
and then
$$ | a_{n_k}-a|<\epsilon$$ for alle $n_k \geq N$ i.e there is a $K$ such that $n_K \geq N$ and then
$$| a_{n_k}-a|<\epsilon$$
for alle $k\geq K$. We conclude that the subsequence converges to $a$

**My questions**

I am not getting the hang of the proof. We have to show that it has the same limit. I somehow get the first two inequalities as that is what it means for a (sub)sequence to converge but after "i.e" I can not follow anymore. What are we actually showing here?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be good if you were clearer what your questions are. If your question is about how to find $K$, notice that $n_k \geq k$ for all $k$. So it actually just suffices to let $K = N$, meaning that if $k \geq N$, then $n_k \geq N$ as well, so the third inequality holds. Does that help?

Comment: @Vercingetorix I have been reflecting over your comment but I guess this is a deeper issue. I do not understand the part after "i.e". isn't the proof done at that point?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this kind of problem, it is better to use, the notation $ (a_{\phi(n)} )$ for a subsequence of the sequence $ (a_n).$

where $ \phi :\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ is a strictly increasing map.
it consequently satisfies
$$(\forall n\in \Bbb N)\;\; \phi(n)\ge n$$

So,
If
$$n\ge N \implies |a_n-L|<\epsilon$$
Then
$$n\ge N\implies \phi(n)\ge N$$
$$\implies |a_{\phi(n)}-L|<\epsilon$$

Comment: My professor is consistently using this notation so I would probably have to get used to it. I have been reflecting over your comment but I guess this is a deeper issue. I do not understand the part after "i.e". isn't the proof done at that point?